# SQL: get gain loss absolute and percentage over previous month

Tags: mysql, sql, window

```
id | year | month | category | value
1    2019    01      apple       3
1    2018    12      apple       2
1    2019    01      carrot      4
```

With this example the expected results is:

```
category | last month | gain or loss % | gain or loss
 apple       2019-01         +50%              +1
 carrot      2019-01         +100%             +4       // Note: no carrot value on previous month
```

Is there any way to do this without doing any expensive join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no missing intermediate months, then a simple lag works (along with some filtering):

```
select category, concat_ws('-', year, month), 
       coalesce(val / prev_value, 1) as gain_loss_rate,
       (val - coalesce(prev_value, 0)) as gain_or_loss
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by id, category order by year, month) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where year = 2019 and month = '01';
```

If you specifically want the most recent month in the data without specifying it, use `rank()` as well:

```
select category, concat_ws('-', year, month), 
       coalesce(val / prev_value, 1) as gain_loss_rate,
       (val - coalesce(prev_value, 0)) as gain_or_loss
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (partition by id, category order by year, month) as prev_value,
             rank() over (order by year desc, month desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select 
    category,
    max(case when rn = 1 then concat(year, '-', month)) last_month,
    coalesce(
        (
            max(case when rn = 1 then value end) 
            - max(case when rn = 2 then value end)
        ) 
        / max(case when rn = 2 then value end), 
    1) gain_or_loss_ratio,
    max(case when rn = 1 then value end) 
        - coalesce(max(case when rn = 2 then value end), 0) gain_or_loss
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by category order by year desc, month desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn in (1, 2)
group by category
```

This lets you compare the *last 2 values* of each category, which is how I understand your question. The third column contains a value between 0 and 1 instead of a percentage, which I find more useful (you can format it as needed on application side).

You can shorten the arithmetic expressions by adding one level of nesting, like so:

```
select
    category,
    last_month,
    coalesce((last_value1 - last_value2) / last_value2, 1) gain_or_loss_ratio,
    last_value1 - coalesce(last_value2, 0) gain_or_loss
from (
    select 
        category,
        max(case when rn = 1 then concat(year, '-', month)) last_month,
        max(case when rn = 1 then value end) last_value1,
        max(case when rn = 2 then value end) last_value2
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            row_number() over(partition by category order by year desc, month desc) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
    where rn in (1, 2)
    group by category
) t
```